# PSR-2 - Should the array opening bracket be on its own line

Tags: php, psr-2

If we are conforming to [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) standards, going off their description for multi-line arguments:

> Argument lists MAY be split across multiple lines, where each
>   subsequent line is indented once. When doing so, the first item in the
>   list MUST be on the next line, and there **MUST be only one argument per
>   line.**
>
> When the argument list is split across multiple lines, the closing
>   parenthesis and opening brace MUST be placed together on their own
>   line with one space between them.

Does that mean arguments should be formatted as the following:

```
return JsonResponse(
    Request::STATUS_OK, 
    [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Example Message Here.'
    ]
)
```

Or is the following format also valid when strictly following their standards?

```
return JsonResponse(
    Request::STATUS_OK, [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Example Message Here.'
    ]
)
```

Comment: The block you've quoted refers to function definitions, not function calls

Comment: @iainn It's the same for method calls (4.6).

Comment: @OP: Your 2nd variant starts the 2nd argument (the array) in the same line as the 1st argument (`Request::STATUS_OK`) which, to  me, seems invalid. (*"there MUST be only one argument per line"*)

Comment: There's been a huge amount of discussion about the interpretations of section 4.6 since it was first published. See the thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/php-fig/-7iArK7WZA0/6MmXRIWGPIMJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [The PSR-2 Meta Document](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/meta/) it has a section regarding multiline arguments, especially referring to arrays and closures:

> Using one or more multi-line arguments (i.e: arrays or anonymous functions) does not constitute splitting the argument list itself, therefore Section 4.6 is not automatically enforced. Arrays and anonymous functions are able to span multiple lines.

So in your case even the following it perfectly valid, including your first example following the specification to the letter.

```
return JsonResponse(Request::STATUS_OK, [
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Example Message Here.'
]);
```

At this level it might just come down to personal preference.